# Helmholtz-Decomposition-weak Formulation in n-dimensional case

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

In the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) about the Helmholtz-Decomposition it says in the section about *Weak Formulation*:

For a slightly smoother vector field u ∈ H(curl, Ω), a similar decomposition holds:
$\mathbf{u}=\nabla\varphi+\mathbf{v}$ $\;\;\;$where $\;\;\;\;$φ ∈ $H^1(Ω)$, v ∈ $(H^1(Ω))^d$.

Does anybody know how to prove this statement or where I can find a proof?

Thanks